# Sorting Apps List Android Java

Tags: java, android

i have a InstalledAppsAdapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class InstalledAppsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InstalledAppsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> mDataSet;

    public InstalledAppsAdapter(Context context, List<String> list){
        mContext = context;
        mDataSet = list;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public CardView mCardView;
        public TextView mTextViewLabel;
        public TextView mTextViewPackage;
        public ImageView mImageViewIcon;

        public ViewHolder (View v){
            super(v);
            // Get the widgets reference from custom layout
            mCardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            mTextViewLabel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.app_label);
            mTextViewPackage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.app_package);
            mImageViewIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public InstalledAppsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.apps_list,parent,false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position){
        // Initialize a new instance of AppManager class
        AppsManager appsManager = new AppsManager(mContext);

        // Get the current package name
        final String packageName = (String) mDataSet.get(position);

        // Get the current app icon
        Drawable icon = appsManager.getAppIconByPackageName(packageName);

        // Get the current app label
        String label = appsManager.getApplicationLabelByPackageName(packageName);

        // Set the current app label
        holder.mTextViewLabel.setText(label);

        // Set the current app package name
        holder.mTextViewPackage.setText(packageName);

        // Set the current app icon
        holder.mImageViewIcon.setImageDrawable(icon);

        // Set a click listener for CardView
        holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Get the intent to launch the specified application
                Intent intent = mContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
                if(intent != null){
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,packageName + " Launch Error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        // Count the installed apps
        return mDataSet.size();
    }

}
```

and AppsManager

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class AppsManager {
    private Context mContext;

    public AppsManager(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    // Get a list of installed app
    public List<String> getInstalledPackages(){
        // Initialize a new Intent which action is main
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,null);

        // Set the newly created intent category to launcher
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        // Set the intent flags
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);

        // Generate a list of ResolveInfo object based on intent filter
        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,0);

        // Initialize a new ArrayList for holding non system package names
        List<String> packageNames = new ArrayList<>();

        // Loop through the ResolveInfo list
        for(ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfoList){
            // Get the ActivityInfo from current ResolveInfo
            ActivityInfo activityInfo = resolveInfo.activityInfo;

            // If this is not a system app package
            if(!isSystemPackage(resolveInfo)){
                // Add the non system package to the list
                packageNames.add(activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);
            }
        }

        return packageNames;

    }

    // Custom method to determine an app is system app
    public boolean isSystemPackage(ResolveInfo resolveInfo){
        return ((resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0);
    }

    // Custom method to get application icon by package name
    public Drawable getAppIconByPackageName(String packageName){
        Drawable icon;
        try{
            icon = mContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packageName);
        }catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Get a default icon
            icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.mipmap.ic_apps);
        }
        return icon;
    }

    // Custom method to get application label by package name
    public String getApplicationLabelByPackageName(String packageName){
        PackageManager packageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();
        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo;
        String label = "Unknown";
        try {
            applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
            if(applicationInfo!=null){
                label = (String)packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo);
            }

        }catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return label;
    }
}
```

i want to sort the adapter with app name not with package name how could i do that ?

i set adapter this way

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext); // new GridLayoutManager(mContext,2);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

// Initialize a new adapter for RecyclerView
mAdapter = new InstalledAppsAdapter(
        mContext,
        new AppsManager(mContext).getInstalledPackages()
);

// Set the adapter for RecyclerView
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

just want to sort the apps list with application name ascending way not on package name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay guys after messing with holders and bla bla simple thing to sort is this

in AppsManager.java

```
Collections.sort(resolveInfoList, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));
```

done

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off if your `InstalledAppsAdapter` was backed by `ApplicationInfo` rather than `String` (the app package name).  You could then create a `Comparator<ApplicationInfo>` which sorts based on `ApplicationInfo#loadLabel()`:

```
final PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
mAdapter.sort(new Comparator<ApplicationInfo>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ApplicationInfo lhs, ApplicationInfo rhs) {
        final String lhsLabel = lhs.loadLabel(pm).toString();
        final String rhsLabel = rhs.loadLabel(pm).toString();
        return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(lhsLabel, rhsLabel);
    }
});
```

You will want `getInstalledPackages` to return a `List<ApplicationInfo>` rather than `List<String>`.  Your adapter should likewise use `List<ApplicationInfo>` for its `mDataSet`.

Comment: @AndroidBeginnerJhon See my update.  The key here is that, instead of storing just the package names in a list, store the entire `ApplicationInfo` object in a list, and base the rest of your code around that.

Comment: yes i got you what you mean to return the Applicationinfo from which we can use application name to sort it out so that packagename and icons go at right positions after sorting but i am confused how to implement it :(

Comment: i tried making holder and added data to it but only one same app is shown always in the list,if you could do a modification in above code would be really help bro